# jQuery + Parse: Functions from for loops

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, for-loop, parse-platform

I am lost.

I am using Parse and jQuery for a project I am working on.  In Parse I have 'Listings' with addresses, prices, titles, etc. My end goal is to have a list of each Listing address and when one is clicked, the rest of the Listing's information is shown.

So far I have listed each listing from Parse using a for loop:

```
var Listings = Parse.Object.extend("Listings");
var query = new Parse.Query(Listings);

query.descending("createdAt");

query.find({

     success: function(results) {

        //alert("Sucessflly retreived " + results.length + " results!");

        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            var object = results[i];

           var houseTitle = object.get("Title");
           var myTitle = $('<h3>' + houseTitle + '</h3>');

           $('container').append(myTitle);
```

My code is working to list each title of the listing so far.  I have no idea where to go from here.  I was thinking I could somehow have another div below the list of Listings that is hidden until clicked. But I dont know how to go about doing this.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ideally, you don't want to spend time loading info onto a page if you don't need to show it.

and I know *I* don't like modal dialogues to keep popping up.

I would put a div below each one with a specific, known id.
but leave it empty.
when the user clicks on the listing link, then create the content for that div (from the data that you have squirreled away), and set the html for that div, and then it should just show.

that div should also have a close or "collapse" button so that you can hide the div.

once the div is up, then you can just hide it.

then if the user tries to open it again, then just show it (ie, use lazy loading)

look here for an interaction pattern:
http://designinginterfaces.com/patterns/list-inlay/

and here: (it's parent page)
http://designinginterfaces.com/patterns/

(ps: an acquaintance of mine wrote that book)

tl;dr:  think first of what interaction pattern you want.  look up on the web for inspiration (pattern sites, or your favorite websites:  how do they do it?)
and then do lazy loading

Comment: Thank you very much! This work very well for what I want to do.